# JQuery validator not working

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, jquery-validate

I have zend form in my html:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="orderForm" class="cmxform">
...
<td valign="top"><br /><label for="cname">Name</label></td><td><?= $this->form->name ?></td><td rowspan="3">
...
```

My zend form(i set attribute for validator):

```
...
    ->setAttrib('class', 'required')
    ->setAttrib('id', 'cname');
...
```

Then i try to call validator(`#nextButton` - not submit, just button):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#nextButton").click(function() {
            $("#orderForm").validate();
        });
```

My validator don't want to do anything, thanks for any help!

Comment: We're troubleshooting a JavaScript (client-side) problem for you, so showing your _rendered_ HTML output is far more useful than showing the Zend code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nextButton").click(function() {
        $("#orderForm").validate();
    });
}); // <- missing ?
```

Your problem is being caused by a misunderstanding about what `.validate()` is really doing here for you.

- `.validate()` is the **initialization** for the plugin... it's not the method for testing the form.
- The validation test is triggered by various events and fully automatic.  There is no need for you to capture the `click` event on the submit button... the plugin does that all by itself.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#orderForm").validate(); // initialize the plugin

});
```

Rendered HTML output:

```
<form id="orderForm">
    <input type="text" id="cname" name="cname" class="required" />
    <button id="nextButton">next</button>
</form>
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/NWga4/**

Remember, your input fields also need a `name` attribute for the plugin to function properly.

---

If you do not wish to submit the form but only "test" the form's validity, use the `.valid()` method...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#orderForm').validate(); // initialize the plugin

    $("#nextButton").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#orderForm').valid(); // trigger a test
    });

});
```

**DEMO #2:  http://jsfiddle.net/QRdzg/**

Answer (score 1):

so many things that you can use to debug... First check your console if there is any error... Second, in your form action attributes put something like # or javascript:void();

And in your js.. try to put validation code outside click event like so

```
$('#orderForm').validate({
     rules: {
         name: required
     }
});

$('#nextButton').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     if( $("#orderForm").valid()){
      $('#orderForm').submit();
     }
});
```

Comment: in console, it's writing valid is not a function

Comment: You do not need a `submit` event inside a `click` handler when using the jQuery Validate plugin... this is all superfluous.